# Child theme's style.css isn't loaded

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm trying to use a child theme on top of [commercial tm-organik theme](http://organik.thememove.com/organik-shop/). I created a subfolder in `/themes/` containing a `style.css` file with the following content:

```
/*
Theme Name: My child theme name
Template: tm-organik
*/
```

The name of the parent theme is correct (I know it's case sensitive so I respected that). In dashboard, child theme is active. Yet child theme `style.css` never gets loaded. Why not?

Comment: Just to make sure -- did you activate the new Theme in `wp-admin` -> `appearance` ?

Comment: Yes, I activated the theme from there.

Comment: Check the parent theme `header.php` and see if `wp_head()` is being called. This is where WordPress loads items into the HTML header. Maybe that theme is so custom that it doesn't load default WordPress tags into the header. Other than that I can't think of anything if the theme activation went well.

Answer (score 0):

Try a more elaborate style.css in your child theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

On the link, in the "How to create a child theme" section you can find the stylesheet header that **must** be used (of course replacing the data with yours):

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

You have to state that your child theme is a child theme of what (template), and give other important info.

I hope this solves your problem.